# retrieve common CSS patterns in websites code

Tags: css, web, design-patterns

I have a collection of **off-line** web sites. Every website has a folder with the site name. (e.g. microspino.com). Those websites are somewhat similar (i.e. same doctype, same basic html structure).

I would like to find a clever way to generate a file with all the recurring/common  patterns for the **CSS** applied to their **index pages**. It could be whatever you think is better, write a script, use the shell etc. and the output could have, again, whatever format.

The goal for me is to analyze and store somewhere the most useful/used CSS rules of the entire collection, updating my findings from time to time.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

**UPDATE**
I don't need only the count but also to extract the most common rules.
Ideally, but this is not a format constraint, I woud like to have:

[count] [css rule]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds ugly but for a one- off time saver you could merge the CSS files into one and import the resulting file into a SQL table and analyse the results with basic TSQL counts?

Comment: This is still a legitimate answer, even after the update.  `SELECT rule FROM css ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 15`  Seems like it would work, right?

Comment: @rockerest Yes, I was only waiting for others to come and provide alternatives.